Counting Problem on a Rubik's Cube

Cain has a Rubik's cube, which is a $3\times 3\times3$ cube made out of $27$ unit cubes, where every cube of a face on the outside can be rotated by any increment of $90^{\circ}$. Pomni's house is a corner unit cube of the Rubik's cube. Cain can only rotate, by an increment of $90^{\circ}, 180^{\circ}, 270^{\circ},$ or $360^{\circ}$, a face that Pomni's house lies on that has not been previous rotated. He wants to perform $6$ rotations so that Pomni's is now positioned the corner opposite to its original starting position. In how many ways can this be performed?

This problem was created by a friend for a small math competition we are creating, but neither of us could figure out a clean solution without using a program. Any ideas on how this might be solved would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Rotate by an increment of 360° ! I suggest that you simplify the question, and consider only rotations of +90° or -90°.

@Lourrran That would not be possible due to parity considerations. All six faces must be turned, each quarter turn moves the room to an adjacent corner, but a opposite corner location can only be reached in an odd number of such steps.

You can ignore the rotation amounts of each face, and just concentrate on the order in which the faces are turned. This face order must be such that the first is one of the three faces containing the room, the last one of the other three faces containing the target location, and such that any two consecutive faces in the sequence are adjacent. For any such sequence, there are $2^5$ choice for rotations that work because any two consecutively moved faces have two corner locations in common that the room could be moved through. Counting the face order sequences is still tricky though.

I was aware that there was no solution. With original configuration (rotation 180° and 360° is accepted), we have 10 moves possible at each step. So $10^5$ combinations of 5 moves. The house can be at 8 different places. With very similar numbers of combinations for each one. If the house is at position (0,0,0), there is no move that can raise the house to final position (1,1,1).

If we are in position(0,0,1) or (0,1,0) or (1,0,0), 1 move is possible to go to (1,1,1) ; if we are in position (0,1,1) or (1,0,1) or (1,1,0), 2 moves are possible to go to (1,1,1) ; and if we are in position (1,1,1), 1 move is possible.  So final count is very close to $10^5 \times \frac{10}{8}$
